How to adhere to interface which requires a Component to be returned, when a component has props
I have a component MyComponent.vue which looks like this:
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
  greeting: string;
}>();
</script>
<template>
<div> {{ props.greeting }} </div>
</template>

I also have a 3rd-party interface that wants me to provide an argument as a Component:
import { type Component } from 'vue';
const doSomething3rdParty = (component: Component)

I know that if MyComponent didn't have props, I could just pass it as is:
doSomething3rdParty(MyComponent);

But is there a way to pass props when passing a Component to a function? Or do I need to move them to some global state, where MyComponent can retrieve them after it was instantiated?

You can wrap the component into a functional one:
import {h} from  'vue';
doSomething3rdParty(() => h(Component, {greeting: 'Hello world'}));

